# What is the different between isAlive() and isConnected() in Zookeeper$Status ? (3.4.5)

Tags: session, connect, apache-zookeeper

Here is the source code, and what made me confuse are the status "closed" and "not_connected".(zookeeper version r3.4.5)

```
public enum States {
    CONNECTING, ASSOCIATING, CONNECTED, CONNECTEDREADONLY,
    CLOSED, AUTH_FAILED, NOT_CONNECTED;

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return this != CLOSED && this != AUTH_FAILED;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether we are connected to a server (which
     * could possibly be read-only, if this client is allowed
     * to go to read-only mode)
     * */
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return this == CONNECTED || this == CONNECTEDREADONLY;
    }
}
```

And if a session go expired(watcher catch an expired event), is it means isAlive() will return false?

Answer (score 1):

I can show you a exapmle to make it clearly.

If zookeeper client state is in CONNECTING, it's ALIVE but not CONNECTED.

Answer (score 0):

The ZooKeeper Sessions states From [ZooKeeper Programmer's Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110043121/http://zookeeper.apache.org:80/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html)

[image: ZooKeeper Sessions]

> And if a session go expired(watcher catch an expired event), is it means isAlive() will return false?

So if a session go expired, isAlive() returns false.